# Change bibitem style

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I use standard bibliography options, it provides me with the following result that is an enumerated list:

```
 8  Atkin A.O. Elliptic curves and primality proving // Mathematics of
    Computation, 1993, Vol. 61, P. 29–68.
 9  Menezes A. Reducing elliptic curve logarithms to logarithms in a finite field
    // IEEE Transactions on Information Theory, 1993, Vol. 39, P. 1639–1646.
10  Menezes A., Elliptic Curve Public Key Cryptosystems. Kluwer Academic
    Publishers, Boston, 1993.
```

I need a slight different bibliography style: text paragraphs with the first line indent, like this:

```
    8 Atkin A.O. Elliptic curves and primality proving // Mathematics of
Computation, 1993, Vol. 61, P. 29–68.
    9 Menezes A. Reducing elliptic curve logarithms to logarithms in a finite field
// IEEE Transactions on Information Theory, 1993, Vol. 39, P. 1639–1646.
    10 Menezes A., Elliptic Curve Public Key Cryptosystems. Kluwer Academic
Publishers, Boston, 1993.
```

How can I change the style for bibliography list in my custom class (derived from `report`)?

Comment: And does your custom class redefines the `thebibliography` environment or does it inherit the definition from `report`? Also, are you using `natbib`?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina It has the `thebibliography` definition, and it's only a copy from the original `report`.

Comment: then the code in my answer should do what you want. Otherwise,  let me know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `thebibliography` environment is built using a list, so you can change the appropriate lengths. In the following example I show such modification using the default definition for the `\thebibliography` commands as defined in `report.cls`. Basically what you have to do, according to your description, is to set `\leftmargin` to `0pt` and `\itemindent` to a positive value (I used `30pt`):

```
\begin{filecontents*}{zzxx.bib}
@book{goossens93,
    author = "Michel Goossens",
    title = "The {LaTeX} Companion",
    year = "1993",
    publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
    address = "Reading, Massachusetts"
}

@article{greenwade93, 
    author = "George D. Greenwade",
    title = "The {C}omprehensive {TeX} {A}rchive {N}etwork ({CTAN})",
    year = "1993",
    journal = "TUGBoat",
    volume = "14",
    number = "3",
    pages = "342--351",
    url=" www.ctan.org"
}

@book{knuth79,
    author = "Donald E. Knuth",
    title = "{TeX} and Metafont, New Directions in Typesetting",
    year = "1979",
    publisher = "American Mathematical Society and Digital Press",
    address = "Stanford"
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{report}

\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{thebibliography}[1]
     {\chapter*{\bibname}%
      \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\bibname}{\MakeUppercase\bibname}%
      \list{\@biblabel{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}%
           {\settowidth\labelwidth{\@biblabel{#1}}%
            \leftmargin=0pt
            \itemindent=30pt
            \@openbib@code
            \usecounter{enumiv}%
            \let\p@enumiv\@empty
            \renewcommand\theenumiv{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}%
      \sloppy
      \clubpenalty4000
      \@clubpenalty \clubpenalty
      \widowpenalty4000%
      \sfcode`\.\@m}
     {\def\@noitemerr
       {\@latex@warning{Empty `thebibliography' environment}}%
      \endlist}
\makeatother

\begin{document} 

\nocite{*}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{zzxx}

\end{document}
```

[image]